# After Paypal integration apple rejects apps

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, payment-gateway

After adding the below framework. Apple has rejected the build.

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
```

Apple has replied with this mail

[image]

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: FYI, the word 'below' is not an adjuctive.

Comment: Do you find UIWebView in you project?

Comment: @Kudos yes. By using "grep -r -F "UIWebView" ." this command in terminal webview has been spotted in Paypal SDK. By below answer I came to know that its deprecated and we have to use Braintree Direct

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Cocoapods.org, [the `PayPal-iOS-SDK` pod is listed as deprecated](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK).

The [README in the original repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/README.md) (where the pod comes from) suggests to use Braintree Payments.

There may also be a [PayPal authored solution too](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sdk-dev/native/).

Answer (score 1):

This is at the top of the PayPal SDK repo

> **Important**: PayPal Mobile SDKs are Deprecated. The APIs powering them will remain operational long enough for merchants to migrate, but the SDKs themselves will no longer be updated. Please use [Braintree Direct](https://www.braintreepayments.com/products/braintree-direct) in [supported countries](https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection). In other countries, use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) and choose the Braintree SDK integration option.